# mat-tab label flex wrap responsive

Tags: angular, angular-material

i have been searching hard about the mat-tab responsive beheivor, but i couldn't find how to wrap the mat-tab...

As you know, when **mat-tab** collapse, it shows two paginator arrows... well i found how to remove them, but also i need to wrap the labels when it collapse.

i tried things like ...

```
.mat-tab-group {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

but nothing happens, Is it possible to do? maybe angular material tabs can not collapse wrap ...